# specifying the function space used in the local Fourier analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

The local Fourier analysis is a technique to analyze operators $A$ defined on lattices $L$.

For simplicity let $L:=\mathbb{Z}$ and  $$A : \{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\} \rightarrow  \{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$$ be some linear operator. For example the discretized laplacian, i.e. $$(Af)(x) := 2f(x) - f(x-1) - f(x+1).$$

To analyze this operator, one applies $A$ onto the wavefunctions $e_k \in \{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$, $e_k(x) = e^{ikx}$, $k\in[0,2\pi)$. 
We find that the $e_k$ are eigenfunctions since $Ae_k(x) = e^{ikx} \cdot (2 - e^{ik} - e^{-ik})$.

My question is, what function space do we analyze here? We do not really analyze $A : \{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\} \rightarrow  \{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$. Instead we restrict ourselves to the domain space where $f$ can be written as a finite sum i.e. $\{f: L \rightarrow \mathbb{C} ,  $ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} c_k e^{ik_i x}\}$, which is smaller than sequence spaces $\ell^\infty$ but larger than $\ell^p$ for fixed $p$, right? Can we specify that space even further?

How can we justify that the analyzation of $A$ applied to the wavefunctions $e^{ikx}$ is the right thing to do? Don't we miss out some information about the functions that cannot be written as linear combinations of the wave functions?